# Как зашить в программу версию продукта с помощью CMake?

Tags: cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)
project(myproject VERSION "0.0.0.0")
include(version)
...
add_subdirectory(...)
add_subdirectory(gui)
...
```

file version.cmake: (считываю версию продукта в переменные)

```
file(READ "${OPTIONS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}_version.txt" tmp)
string(REGEX MATCHALL "[0-9]" tmp_list "${tmp}")

list (GET tmp_list 0 PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR)
list (GET tmp_list 1 PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR)
list (GET tmp_list 2 PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH)

execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} svnversion -n OUTPUT_VARIABLE SVN_REV)

string(REGEX MATCH "[0-9]*" SVN_REV "${SVN_REV}")
```

в файле gui/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} WIN32
${SOURCES}
${HEADERS}
${ABOUT_HEADER}
${RESOURCE_FILE}
)
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION "0.1")
```

Хочу добиться чтобы в свойствах екзешника была зашита версия и описание.
[image: Свойства исполняемого файла]

Comment: вижу что ответа давно нет, но он есть на английской версии, но боюсь неправильно интерпретировать т.к. не далал такого. поэтому вот ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693100/how-to-generate-windows-dll-versioning-information-with-cmake

Comment: @Komdosh, спасибо, это помогло